# connect a jquery function to bootstrap's carousel slide event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I created the following function:

```
//Toggle height of header-foto function
function height_toggler() {
    $('body').toggleClass('large-slider small-slider',500);
    $('#height-toggler').find('i').toggleClass('fa-rotate-270 fa-rotate-90');
}
```

I call this function when a user click the button:

```
// bind the function to a click on the toggler
$('#height-toggler').click( function() {
    height_toggler();
});
```

this works perfectly, you can see it live on [this page](http://duijnisveld.wpengine.com/)

My client also wants this function bound on the Bootstrap Carousel's `slide` [event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events) and only on pages with 100% height carousels. 
I came up with the following code, but this triggers everytime the carousel slides (which I understand). How can I make it trigger only on the first slide after page load?

```
if( $('body').hasClass('large-slider') ) { //only perform this on large sliders
    $('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        height_toggler();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

```
if( $('body').hasClass('large-slider') ) { //only perform this on large sliders
  $('.carousel').one('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    height_toggler();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you want an event to be executed only once, you can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of `.on()`

```
if( $('body').hasClass('large-slider') ) { //only perform this on large sliders
    $('.carousel').one('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        height_toggler();
    });
}
```